# Android show location on create google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Good day,

at the moment I am creating an Android application that will show the user their current location on a map. Sadly I can't seem to zoom at the current location of the user in the OnCreate method. It seems to work in a OnMapClick method.

I would like to get rid of the OnMapClick method and show the current location of the user when the map is loaded.

the code below is part of the OnCreate method of the map class

```
Settings setting = new Settings();
    setting.saveSettings(Maps.this);
    LocationManager locationManager =(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Here is the code of the OnLocationChanged method

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int)(location.getLatitude());
    int lng =(int)(location.getLongitude());
    LatLng loc = new LatLng(lat,lng);
    myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 15));
    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
```

I posses an API key and have the map in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help you...

my listener

> private LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
>
> ```
>   @Override
>     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
>     }
>
>    @Override
>     public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
>     }
>
>    @Override
>     public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
>     }
>
>    @Override
>     public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
>     // will get the location lat long
>     }
> };
> ```

code to start the location manager update listener

> ```
> LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
>         if (mLocationManager != null) {
>             Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
>             criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
>             String prividerName = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
>             if (prividerName != null) {
>                 mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(prividerName, 30 * 1000, 0, listener);
> ```

Once you get the lat/long u can plot the location details as below

> ```
> GoogleMap googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
>             R.id.map)).getMap();
> LatLng current = new LatLng(mUserLatitude, mUserLongitude);
> googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(current).title("Current Location"))
>             .showInfoWindow();
> googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
> googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
> googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current, 10));
> ```

Comment: What would be the correct way to obtain the latitude and longitude to get your sample to work?

Comment: Hello @krian777, sadly I still can't get the current gps coördinates when the map is loaded. Please check my post below.

Comment: you can declare instance variables as,                                                             private double mUserLatitude = Double.MAX_VALUE;
private double mUserLongitude = Double.MAX_VALUE;                   and update them in as                                            @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
      mUserLatitude = loc.getLatitude();
      mUserLongitude = loc.getLongitude();
    }

Comment: thank you for the example, if I start the application now it's current location are 90.0, -52.0 according to the application. These coördinates are a bit off.

Comment: use Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE and add the permissions in the manifest, have a look at the various criteria.

Comment: I think that my last comment created a bit of confusion, the coordinates 90.0,-52.0 are in the ocean next to greenland while my current location is in Europe.

Comment: I found a way to get the current location ofthe user thanks to the LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER. I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have a fix on the location yet. I would suggest doing

```
myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
myMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
```

then in you `onLocationChanged` put a boolean for a first load or something so it does not go to the location every time the location changes and then do the camera movement in there

Answer (score 0):

I hope this piece of code can help to clearify my question.

the code below is my LocationListener

```
private LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
      @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

       @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

       @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

       @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
           double lat = loc.getLatitude();
           double lng = loc.getLongitude();


        }
    };
```

the latitude and longitude ares saved in antoher class,
the code below show my way of initialzing the map.

```
    String locLat = ((Settings)this.getApplication()).getLat();
    String locLng = ((Settings) this.getApplication()).getLng();
    double DlocLat = Double.parseDouble(locLat);
    double DlocLng = Double.parseDouble(locLng);

    myMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    LatLng current = new LatLng(DlocLat,DlocLng);
    myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(current).title("Current Location")).showInfoWindow();
    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);//show the location on the map
    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);//show the regular google maps
    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current, 10));
```